# Replace chracters in Notepad++ quickly

Tags: notepad++

I am using *`Notepad++`*. I am having some entries as below:

```
001:0> class Item
002:1>   def initialize(id)
003:2>     @id = id
004:2>   end
```

Now is there anyway to quickly remove those `001:0>,002:1>...` in one shot and get them as below:

```
 class Item
   def initialize(id)
     @id = id
   end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Replace` dialog, and check the box `Regular Expressions` at the bottom.

[image]

Find:

```
^(\d+?:\d+?>)(.*)
```

[RegexBuddy's](http://regexbuddy.com) Explanation tree:

- Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks
- Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string 
  or after a line break character) «^»
- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into 
  backreference number 1 «(\d+?:\d+?>)»
- Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+?»
- Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, 
  expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
- Match the character “:” literally «:»
- Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+?»
- Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, 
  expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
- Match the character “>” literally «>»
- Match the regular expression below and capture its match into 
  backreference number 2 «(.*)»
- Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
- Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving 
  back as needed (greedy) «*»

Replace:

```
\2
```

This replaces the entire match with the content of capture group `2` (see above)

Click `Replace All`

[image]

Note that the regular expression for the find portion will also match numbers in the format `00:0>`, `0000:00>`, `00000000:00000000>`, and so forth. If that won't work for you, change the regular expression to:

```
 ^(\d{3}+:\d>)(.*)
```

Comment: why `\2`? and could you `(\d+?:\d+?>)(.*)` explain this?

Comment: I've edited to explain the first find and replace expressions. If you need more, you might visit the [RegexBuddy website](http://regexbuddy.com), where you'll find a link to a regular expressions tutorial that's pretty good (as is RegexBuddy if you're going to use a lot of regular expressions and use Windows).

Comment: Thanks for your help and giving me the link.